# Optimization for text rendering

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, optimization, uikit, core-graphics

I have text displayed within a UIView which again is located within a UIScrollView.
The font size/size of the text should change its size based on its distance from a certain point on the screen.

There are many of these items on the screen which at a high rate need to rerender the same text at different sizes.

How can I optimize this in order for the text rendering to be less of a bottleneck?

Comment: How are you currently drawing the text?

Comment: drawString:withContext:inRect:withFont:textAlpha

Comment: There's no such method built in in Cocoa Touch. What Apple API are you using to draw the text?

Comment: ops - that was my wrapper... 
Should have been:  drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode